# Network Databases - 2

Tags: discussion

I fail to see why my previous question was closed. I merely asked whether or not there were any free/open source network (IDMS-type) databases, with the implication that, if there were, an indication of what they were would be made.

You say "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format". Why not, it's a straight question?

"We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.". A simple reply would not "solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." - it's a straight factual answer.

Answer (score 8):

That type of question generally isn't welcome on Stack Exchange sites. They're sometimes referred to as list questions, or [shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and don't fit the model.

Search engines are good at getting you lists of "things that do X" - that's exactly what they're built for. They also keep their results relatively up to date. So that's what you should use to locate a product/implementation.

Wikipedia also maintains quite a few lists of products, with feature comparisons. That's another good place to look.

You could also try in chat. Some people might help with this type of request there.

A tip: you don't appear to have read the [about](https://dba.stackexchange.com/about) page, or the [faq](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) - please do read those, they've got important information about how DBA.SE works.

Comment: Thanks, Mat. I've already tried other avenues.

Comment: Including chat here? Anyway, if you can't find something with any of those, might be an indication that what you're looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: I agree with Mat, if you've even tried our chat channel and can't get any help there, then you may be looking for the wrong things. I'm still not sure from the Q what exactly it is you're looking for, so I'll stop by the main site and see what's listed.